# Failed to execute jsonpath in json_exporter

Tags: json, prometheus, metrics, exporter, prometheus-json-exporter

The goal is this: go to the url with a whip and take information from it, then transfer this information to the alert. So that when a letter arrived that something was broken, it was immediately written what exactly (and what exactly broke was written in the check).

I've got the Healthcheck.:

```
{
  "status": "OK",
  "description": "All good",
  "sql": null
}
```

I need to get the **description**. As a result, I made such a config, focusing on examples:

```
modules:
  default:
    headers:
      MyHeader: MyHeaderValue
    metrics:
      - name: jsonhc
        type: object
        help: healthcheks description
        path: '{.description}'
        labels:
          env: prod
        values:
          status: 1
          description: '{.description}'
```

The answer I get is this:

> json_exporter  | ts=2023-06-22T11:12:38.760Z caller=collector.go:136 level=error msg="Failed to execute jsonpath" err="description is not found" path={.description} data=""All good""
>
> json_exporter  | ts=2023-06-22T11:12:38.761Z caller=collector.go:88 level=error msg="Failed to extract value for metric" path={.description} err="description is not found" metric="Desc{fqName: "jsonhc_description", help: "healthcheks description", constLabels: {}, variableLabels: [env]}

The data I get is correct, but I can't take it for an alert. When I check the curl for targets, it's not there.

I ran:

```
#curl http://localhost:7979/probe
```

And received:

> Target parameter is missing

I've tried different variants of the `path` variable (such as `'$.*' and '{ [*] }'`) but it doesn't work. Please help me figure it out is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It doesn't address the `Failed to execute` issue but I think you need to reference the `module` and `target` in the GET `probe`, i.e. `http://localhost:7979/probe?module=default&target={healthcheck}` where `{healthcheck` is the URL of your healthcheck endpoint.

Comment: I think it doesn't affect the exporter's behavior but the Healthcheck JSON is malformed and should not include the comma (`,`) after the final value `"sql": null`

Comment: @DazWilkin It's a typo. There is no comma in reality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem was with Healthcheck itself. This is what it was supposed to be.

```
{
  "healthcheck": [
    {
      "status": "OK",
      "description": "All good",
      "sql": null
    }
  ]
}
```

After that the module worked as I wanted it to.
Also, to do what I had in mind, I needed a module like this.

```
path: '{.healthcheck[?(@.status != "OK")]}'
```

And then in case there was not "OK", I set up an alert so that I would be sent an email when the status == 1